# I have made a border inside of a wrap panel programatically, but now I need to add 2 label into that border. How can I do that programatically as well

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, border

So currently I have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            WrapPanel.Children.Add(new Border { Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#C7DFFC"), Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(5, 5, 5, 5), Height = 50, Width = 50, Name = ("RAM" + i) });
        }
```

This creates 100 borders inside my WrapPanel. Now I need to create 2 labels in each of those borders. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Border border = new Border();
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
//add child controls like labels etc
panel.Children.Add(child1);
panel.Children.Add(child2);
//set the panel as child of border
border.Child = panel;
//nod add border to 
WrapPanel.Children.Add(border);
```